# Angular Material Autocomplete show more items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am using the [Autocomplete demo](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/autocomplete) of Angular Material.

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <md-content layout-padding layout="column">
    <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
      <p>Use <code>&lt;md-autocomplete&gt;</code> with custom templates to show styled autocomplete results.</p>
      <md-autocomplete
          ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled"
          md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache"
          md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem"
          md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)"
          md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
          md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)"
          md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)"
          md-item-text="item.name"
          md-min-length="0"
          placeholder="Pick an Angular repository"
          md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
        <md-item-template>
          <span class="item-title">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/icons/octicon-repo.svg"></md-icon>
            <span> {{item.name}} </span>
          </span>
          <span class="item-metadata">
            <span class="item-metastat">
              <strong>{{item.watchers}}</strong> watchers
            </span>
            <span class="item-metastat">
              <strong>{{item.forks}}</strong> forks
            </span>
          </span>
        </md-item-template>
      </md-autocomplete>
    </form>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

The problem is that this demo only displays 3 items in the result list. How to display more items in the result list ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)` should return the array!

Comment: where exactly it display 3 items?